# How to convert YOLOv7 model into core ML model for pose detection

Tags: coreml, yolov7, pose-detection

How to convert YOLOv7 for pose detection into Core ML model to run model or application on ios device.
the refrence for the model is :

https://github.com/googlesamples/mediapipe/blob/main/examples/pose_landmarker/python/%5BMediaPipe_Python_Tasks%5D_Pose_Landmarker.ipynb

I already detected the pose using YOLOv7 model for android and web browser.

iam doing it for video input and visualizing it for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `YOLOv7` model already converted to `MLModel` here:

https://github.com/john-rocky/CoreML-Models#yolov7

If you want to convert the model yourself, please share your `coremltools` conversion script and I will take a look.